# Python Django Import Error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am newbie to django.I m using python 2.6 with django 1.3v I am trying to create a simple blog application.When I access the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ I'm getting the error `No module named urls`.I gave this 
 `url(r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls'))` in urls.py.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.blog',
    #Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentatio    n:  
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
 )
```

models.py

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib import admin

   class BlogPost(models.Model):
     title=models.CharField(max_length=150)
     body=models.TextField()
     timestamp=models.DateTimeField()

   admin.site.register(BlogPost)
```

Error:

```
ImportError at /admin/

No module named urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named urls

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/bharathi/development/python/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Check `INSTALLED_APPS`, it should have `'django.contrib.admin'`.

Comment: Yes.`django.contrib.admin` uncommented!

Comment: Can you paste the code in your urls.py ?

Comment: Try uncommenting # from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

Comment: Uncommented.But I am getting `No module named urls`

Comment: Which file does it give the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.There was improper indentation.I fixed it.

Comment: Always good to "show invisibles" in your editor when working with Python, if you have such an option.

Comment: Tabs or spaces, pick one. If in doubt, use spaces. ... Shoot, if in doubt, do what [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable django.contrib.admin in your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS tuple?

Django will only know of python modules (also called 'django app's in django terminology) if you have state them in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple in your django project's settings.py file.